# Why does indexing need to be referenced?

Tags: indexing, rust, slice

I'm currently learning Rust coming from JavaScript.

My problem is the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let name = String::from("Tom");
    let sliced = name[..2];
    println!("{}, {}", name, sliced);
}
```

This doesn't work. Saying `"doesn't have a size known at compile-time"`.

To fix this I need to add `&` the referencing operator.

```rust
fn main() {
    let name = String::from("Tom");

    let sliced = &name[..2];

    println!("{}, {}", name, sliced);
}
```

I know I need to add `&` before name and `&` is the referencing operator. But I just don't know why I actually need to do that?

By referencing a variable the reference refers to variable `name` but does not own it. The original value will not get dropped if my reference gets out of scope. Does that mean that the variable gets out of scope if i do `name[...]` and the variable gets dropped and because of that i need to create a reference to it to prevent that?

Could somebody explain me that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 second works. I just want to know what the `&` exactly do that it made my code work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know I need to add `&` before name and `&` is the referencing operator. But I just don't know why I actually need to do that.

I understand where the confusion come from, because when you look at [`index()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) it returns `&Self::Output`. *So it already returns a reference, what's going on?*

---

It's because the indexing operator is *syntactic sugar* and uses the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait. However, while it uses [`index()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) which does return a reference, that is not how it is desugared.

In short **`x[i]`** is not translated into **`x.index(i)`**, but actually to **`*x.index(i)`**, so the reference is immediately dereferenced. *That's how you end up with a `str` instead of a `&str`.*

```
let foo = "foo bar"[..3]; // str
// same as
let foo = *"foo bar".index(..3); // str
```

That's why you need to add the `&` to get it *"back"* to a reference.

```rust
let foo = &"foo bar"[..3]; // &str
// same as
let foo = &*"foo bar".index(..3); // &str
```

Alternatively, if you call [`index()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) directly, then it isn't implicitly dereferenced of course.

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

let foo = "foo bar".index(..3); // &str
```

[Trait `std::ops::Index` - Rust Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html):

> `container[index]` is actually syntactic sugar for `*container.index(index)`

*The same applies to [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html).*

Comment: could you link me to the `index` method? i cannot find it in the docs. It is called method in rust right?

Comment: I already linked it, click any of `index()` in the answer. If you're curious about where it's mentioned, then look at the top of the documentation for [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html)

Comment: okey thank you i will read about it in detail. comming from js to rust is like jumping into the cold water. or freezed water. however thank you for the explanation